# How i store the dictionary in my sqlite database

Tags: android, eclipse

I am new in android and want to develop a offline dictionary application. Is there is any way to store the downloaded dictionary into the database and after that retrieve the dictionary data to compare with the user input.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read this tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: Take a look into Searchable Dictionary http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html

Answer (score 0):

I already did this to my dictionaries:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=e-Biene%20DEV&hl=en

You can make conversion to your simple database, tblLanguage1[word, translation] tblLanguage2[word, translation]

to (SQLite format [extract it from emulator], and then attach this converted SQLite db with your App offline).

It will be quick and fast for searching.

and Use: DB created in emulator with structure like: Tables:

tbllang1_Content 
tbllang1_segments
tbllang1_segdir

use this instead of simple db.

- Cursor Query...to quick search for user inputs.